# Ionic / Angular 2: Use one component multiple times in NavController

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Is there an ability in ionic to use one component to display hierarchical data with lists in every level and navigate to it via `navController.push(theComponent)`?

I have json data that have the following structure:

```
list
   field1
   sublist
      field1
      subsublist
         ...
   field1
   sublist
      field1
      subsublist
         ...
```

I wrote a component in ionic that displays the list. By clicking a list entry I wanted to display the sub list of the this entry with the same component. I tried this:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'template.html'
})

export class MyComponent {
    items = []; // Items of a level to be displayed
    constructor (public nav: NavController)
    {
    }
openItemClick(sublist) {
   this.items = sublist;
   this.nav.push(this); // This will be crash!!
 }
}
```

I become a `Runtime error: Uncaught (in promise): false.`
It is not possible to use the same instance of the component. Is there an ability to instantiate new instance at this point and use it in `this.nav.push(newInstance)`?

Comment: this means that your `items` object is empty and it can resolve them into the child components

Comment: items will be set elsewhere (over parameter or service). I don't have a complete solution for this now. I have hierarchical data that looks exactly the same in each level and want to navigate throw it. The same component must be used because the depth of the data hierarchy is variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` is an instance, while you're expected to `push` a class. I'm assuming that you originally navigate to your list like this:

```
this.nav.push(MyComponent, list);
```

So you should change your method a bit:

```
openItemClick(sublist) {
    this.nav.push(MyComponent, sublist);
}
```